# Creating a dictionary in javascript from a fetch request

Tags: javascript, dictionary, fetch-api

I am trying to feed a fetch request json htmlcontent into a dictionary but keep getting 'invalid syntax :' errors and as a primarily python person I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why.

A basic version of the syntax looks as follows:

```
fetch(URL).then(result => result.json()).then(data => {"Data":data['htmlcontent']});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return an object literal from an arrow funtion, you need to wrap it in an extra set of parentheses - not entirely intuitive I agree.

```
fetch(URL).then(result => result.json()).then(data => ({"Data":data['htmlcontent']}));
// ---------------------------------------------------^----------------------------^
```

The other option is to use a traditional `return` syntax - but its a bit longer with extra `{}`

```
fetch(URL).then(result => result.json()).then(data => { 
     return {"Data":data['htmlcontent']};
});
```